# How do you combine salah?

Tags: salat, fiqh, combining-prayers

**How do you combine salah?**

For example, if you are combining Maghrib and Isha, do you pray the fard of Maghrib, the Sunnah of maghrib and then pray fard of Isha, Sunnah of Isha and Witr of Isha?

The question is in relation to '[Is joining Maghrib and Isha salah together everyday for 2 months allowed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39914/is-joining-maghrib-and-isha-salah-together-everyday-for-2-months-allowed)' as I need to know how to combine prayer and I never combined prayer before.

Comment: So would you pray 3 fard for Maghrib then 4 fard for Isha, so when do you pray the Sunnah and the Witr?

Comment: @Uma In which order though? Would you pray 2 Sunnah for Maghrib then 2 Sunnah for Isha and then 3 witr for Isha?

Comment: Salat is fard when its time has come. When the time of next Salat has come it is not fard anymore. At this case you should do the current Salat on-time and if missed others you can pray them after current fard even order is not an issue. For example if you haven't prayed for the whole day. Then you should start with Isha' first then do the others at any order.

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old question but it would be helpful to specify whether you are looking for a Sunni or Shia POV. You can specify that with an [edit] to the tags. Otherwise, if expect a good answer to explain both views.

Answer (score -1):

There are several different opinions on the matter. Another opinion besides the one offered is to pray 3 rakaa for maghrib then pray 2 rakaa for Isha. There are also different opinions that come with the length of time that you can combine, 2 weeks being one opinion for someone who knows exactly how long they will stay away.

Comment: Qasr Jamah is different than Jamah.

Comment: It's an opinion within jami3

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if the word "combine" is related to "Collection and concatenation" (Gama' and Kasr) جمع و قصر for the prayers.

so let's first explain what is collection and concatenation of prayers.
it means that in some circumstances you are allowed to pray the four rakaa' prayers like Zuhr, Asr and Isha' in a short version of 2 prayer however it should be concatenated to another prayer.

for example you can pray Zuhr (2 rakaa') followed by Asr (2 rakaa') at the time of either one of them.

and you can pray Maghrib (3 rakaa') followed by Ishaa (2 rakaa') at the time of either one of them.

when combining two prayers you shouldn't leave long period between two of them, as once you finish the prayer of the first one (Zuhr or Maghrib) start the Ikama call of the proceeding prayer (Maghrib or Ishaa).

When to combine prayers? During travel. to define traveling it means you travel for something that doesn't contradict with Islam so the travel can't be for the sake of doing something against Islam. the travel period should be equal to 3 days walking. (no matter how fast the modern method of transportation) a distance of 80 km is considered a travel so if you are traveling for a trip that is more that 80 km, you are allowed to combine prayers during the travel.

you actually combine prayer during the travel, not before you travel and after you reach your destination place you can still combine prayer for 3 more days.

in case you pray in group gamaa' you will not combine the prayer and pray as the residents.

in case you mean to combine that for any reason you missed a prayer and the proceeding prayer time has come. you do pray the one on-time then do the one you missed after it not before. for example if you missed the Maghrib prayer and Ishaa azan has raised you do pray Ishaa first then Maghrib.

Comment: You can combine your salah anytime and not just in travelling and in travelling you shorten it while if you combine it normally, you don't shorten it.

Answer (score -2):

Hadith

وَحَدَّثَنِي حَرْمَلَةُ بْنُ يَحْيَى، أَخْبَرَنَا ابْنُ وَهْبٍ، أَخْبَرَنِي يُونُسُ، عَنِ ابْنِ شِهَابٍ، أَنَّأَخْبَرَهُ أَنَّ أَبَاهُ قَالَ جَمَعَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم بَيْنَ الْمَغْرِبِ وَالْعِشَاءِ بِجَمْعٍ لَيْسَ بَيْنَهُمَا سَجْدَةٌ وَصَلَّى الْمَغْرِبَ ثَلاَثَ رَكَعَاتٍ وَصَلَّى الْعِشَاءَ رَكْعَتَيْنِ ‏.‏ فَكَانَ عَبْدُ اللَّهِ يُصَلِّي بِجَمْعٍ كَذَلِكَ حَتَّى لَحِقَ بِاللَّهِ تَعَالَى ‏.‏

Ubaidullah b. 'Abdullah b. 'Umar reported on the authority of his father (Allah be pleased with them) that Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) combined the sunset and 'Isha', prayers at Muzdalifa and there was no prostration (i.e. any rak'ahs of Sunan or Nawafil prayers) in between them. He observed three rak'ahs of the sunset prayer and two rak'ahs of the 'Isha' prayer, and 'Abdullah (b. 'Umar) observed the prayers in this very manner (at Muzdalifa) until he met his Lord.

Sahih Muslim 1288 a 
In-book : Book 15, Hadith 315 
USC-MSA web (English) : Book 7, Hadith 2952  (deprecated)
Sahih Muslim

Hope this will help ...