# Can someone be an Athari Hanafi?

Tags: hanafi, aqidah

There are four classical schools of thought about fiqh (Hanafi, Hanbali, Shafii, Maliki). Then there are also three Sunni schools of thought about some Aqeedah issues (Athari/Hanbali, Ashari, Maturidi).

Hanafis are generally Maturidi. I sometimes come across some Muslims, who are of the opinion, that one should not be Hanafi and Athari at the same time.

Can a practicing Hanafi adhere to the Athari school of thought? Or is the Maturidi school of thought and Hanafi school of thought so much interconnected, that it is difficult to have a different understanding?

For example Shaikh Akram Nadwi and Abu‘l Izz are Athari Hanafis, but they are criticised by many Hanafis. I know these are advanced topics, which shouldn’t be discussed deeply by layman, but this question has a big impact on the choice of books I read about my religion.

Comment: This is already addressed in https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35631/13438